# Queueing reports in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, marketing-cloud, distributed-marketing

I want a list of all email templates which are in queue and need to make a report for the same.
Can anyone guide me with this requirement if anytime anyone came across this Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Is this for 'User-Initiated' / 'Scheduled' sends  (e.g. Automation Studio emails)  or are you looking for the queue of messages on Triggered Send Definitions?

Comment: I am looking for email templates which goes into queue or which are in queue and to make a report for the same.

Comment: Repeating the same phrase which was confusing in the first place does not help me to help you.